# Adding files to TFS Programatically using C# code

Tags: c#, tfs

I am working on an app which fetches few files from a specified path and move to TFS on a button click. My first question is , is it possible to add new files to TFS programatically using C#?. If yes, then is there any restriction on the file types we can add to TFS?. Below is the code i have tried to create a workspace in TFS.

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(<tfs uri>));

tfs.EnsureAuthenticated();
VersionControlServer vcs = tfs.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
Workspace ws = vcs.CreateWorkspace("DCSCode");    

//"I:temp" is the location of files which needs to be 
  //moved to TFS
int r = ws.PendAdd(@"I:temp");
```

Comment: there is no problem statement here. what are we supposed to do?

Comment: Read the TFS API documentation, or result that comes out on "Add file Tfs programatically" Those word in any order.

Comment: First we're not your army. Second please provide an example of what you've tried.

Comment: Why should we do your job? Please show what you´ve tried already and where *speidically* you´re stuck.

Comment: Hi, Sorry for insufficient information provided. I am creating an app where on a button click , files from a specific folders has to be moved to TFS. These files are DCS code files(DCS is a data transformation tool). i have tried below, code i created a workspace and tried to add a file to this workspace. But when i verify in TFS, i dont see the workspace being created.

Comment: Hi, Sorry for insufficient information provided. I am creating an app where on a button click , files from a specific folders has to be moved to TFS. These files are DCS code files(DCS is a data transformation tool). i have tried below, code i created a workspace and tried to add a file to this workspace. But when i verify in TFS, i dont see the workspace being created.My question would be, is it possible to add new files to TFS programatically?. If yes, then is there any restrictions on the type of files which can be added?

Comment: TfsTeamProjectCollection tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(<tfs uri>"));

            tfs.EnsureAuthenticated();

            VersionControlServer vcs = tfs.GetService<VersionControlServer>();

            Workspace ws = vcs.CreateWorkspace("DCSCode");    
            //"I:\temp" is the path where dcs code files are present
            int r = ws.PendAdd(@"I:\temp");

Comment: The question has been closed you need to edit it and include the methods you have you have tried.

Comment: Besides adding that code to the question, you also need to tell us what problems you are having with it?  Are you getting any errors?  Unexpected results?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway I am not getting any errors or exceptions, but I couldn't see the workspace getting created either. As mentioned earlier, my question itself is  is it possible to add new files to TFS programmatically using C#?. If yes, then is there any restriction on the file types we can add to TFS?. I am new to this forum, so I apologise for any data insufficiency/mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `create a new or get the existing workspace` ->  `pend changes` -> `check in those changes` -> `resolve the conflict` if you have.

A related code snippet for your reference:

```
//Get the current workspace
WS = versionControl.GetWorkspace(workspaceName, versionControl.AuthorizedUser);     

//Mapping TFS Server and code generated
WS.Map(tfsServerFolderPath,localWorkingPath);

//Add all files just created to pending change
int NumberOfChange = WS.PendAdd(localWorkingPath,true);
//Get the list of pending changes
PendingChange[] pendings = WS.GetPendingChanges(tfsServerFolderPath,RecursionType.Full);

//Auto check in code to Server
WS.CheckIn(pendings,"CodeSmith Generator - Auto check-in code.");
```

You can also find a sample here : [Programatically checkin file to TFS using C#](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/buckh/2012/03/10/team-foundation-version-control-client-api-example-for-tfs-2010-and-newer/)

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I will try this.